# How to add a image in background and a scrolling rectangle on it?

Tags: css

Sorry if my question is not well asked !

I would create a website with a background picture and on a layer a square with all my text. But the square will be bigger than the screen in term of height. This is my actual code :

```html
<html>
...
    <body style="background-image: url(rs/bg32.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; size : 100% 100%">
        <div class="alpha layer"; style="background-color: #ffffff70; height: 100px; margin: 20px 10px">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's create the website in picture 1.
[image: picture 1] ( yes there is "hello" written inside it, cause I've tried to put something in it and see if it solve my problem but apparently not at all)

But when I set a height bigger than the screen size, everything goes wrong ( picture 2 and 3 ).

scale at 100% : [image: picture2]

scale at 25 % : [image: picture3]

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You set your background-size to `cover`, so as the body grows in height, of course the image will scale up. What's your expected result?

Comment: I would my picture demensionned to cover the whole background wihout repeatition and be rescale to user screen size like he/she could see the entire picture as the background

Comment: `Sorry if my question is not well asked !` . Yes, it's not :). First, try using external CSS files for styles and do not write inline. You have `background-size: cover; size : 100% 100%` . Cover sets the image to cover the whole body element. But `size:100% 100%` doesn't exist as a style attribute. also `;` after `class="alpha layer"` is not valid HTML

Comment: What should the question title be ? I don't know well html terms

Comment: I've removed size and got this : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/42/4/1571314105-sans-titre5.png

Comment: @MihaiT `size` was new to me, too, and it's apparently a new property but it doesn't work in any browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: that `size` you are referring to has nothing to do with what the OP wanted to use it for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `html` and `body` to a height of 100% and `background-attachment: fixed` on the body to keep the background image from scrolling:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(//placekitten.com/1920/1080);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

div.alpha.layer {
  background-color: #ffffff70;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alpha layer" ; style="">
</div>
```